# Not able to connect AWS ES & Kibana using filebeat

Tags: filebeat

We have done some POC in our local ES (local server), but when I am trying to configure AWS Elasticsearch & kibana service in filebeat it's showing below error:

```
Index setup finished.
Loading dashboards (Kibana must be running and reachable)
Exiting: 1 error: error loading index pattern: returned 401 to import file: <nil>. Response: {"statusCode":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Authentication required"}
```

- Filebeat version: 7.12 OSS (7.10 tried bust same issue)
- AWS Elasticsearch & kibana 7.10
- logstash not used

Plz can sombody help in that.

Comment: exactly the same situation and same error. I have tried to create the index by curl command, it works fine, but it can't work by filebeat.

Comment: finally I found we can ignore this error, just run `./filebeat -e` will send logs to elastic search service with no errors.

Comment: Check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55004582/connecting-filebeat-to-kibana/68334045#68334045